# What happens if I put Text inside a <section> tag in HTML without any other tag such as <p> etc.?

Tags: html, tags, element

As you can see from the screenshot below, I placed some text inside the  tag without any other element such as

. When I view it, the test is shown on the HTML page. But is this a legal way?

[image: Screenshot of section tag without any other element inside it]

Comment: Please do not use images for text.  And I dont see a div anywhere

Comment: Hi @RohitGupta! Thanks for responding. So I didn't put a div, instead, I put the Section. Please forgive me for making rookie mistakes as I am just learning web development. And I was wondering if I simply put some text inside the section without putting any <P>, would that suffice? Hope I could make it clear.

Comment: Yes, section doesnt have any restrictions like that. its a divider for your page. With or without <p>, its fine.